# Can I use a symbol as a record key in typescript

Tags: typescript

I would like to use a symbol as an object key in typescript, but when I try the following code

```
class Item
{
  key = Symbol('item');
}

const startingItem = new Item();

const items: Record<Item['key'], Item> = { [startingItem.key]: startingItem };

const item = items[startingItem.key];
```

I get the following error about not being able to use symbol as an index

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'symbol' can't be used to index type 'Record<symbol, Item>'
```

The hint for the Record utility type says `type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }` so I'm not sure why I'm getting an error since it seems like this should be possible?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38009

Comment: According to this issue link on Github, the problem was fixed in October 2022.

Answer (score 2):

This code works, but does it work for your case?

```js
class Item
{
  static readonly key: unique symbol = Symbol('item');
}

const startingItem = new Item();

const items: Record<typeof Item.key, Item> = { [Item.key]: startingItem };

const item = items[Item.key];
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wee6gw)

Comment: Thanks, but key definitely can't be static since each item needs to have a unique key